# Easy way to Post HTTPS JSON data (header+body) using Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, post

After reading multiple internet posts related to "`JSON POST commands`" in NodeJS I'm now totally lost! Have tried to create an easy script to send data to a device Restful API interface using https. Without any luck...

> JSON string needs to contain: a Header incl. (Basic)Auth Token & Body
>   content something similar like: 
>   '{"address":address,"address6":"","comment":"","duids":[],"hostnames":[],"interface":""};

Hoping that someone has a good example available or can point me into right direction again.

Comment: Can you share something you tried? If it doesn't work somebody might be able to point out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-built module https to make a REST API call, the request signature is as follows:

https.request(url[, options][, callback])

In your case, you can try following code:

```
var options = {
   host: 'host-name',
   port: 443,
   path: 'api-path',
   method: 'POST',
   // authentication headers
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + passw).toString('base64')
   }   
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue just few days ago, and I've ended up creating a super tiny module called [json-post](https://github.com/WebReflection/json-post#json-post).

```
const jsonPOST = require('json-post');
// or import jsonPOST from 'json-post'

jsonPOST(
  'https://whatever:5000/seriously',
  // your JSON data as object
  {hello: 'world'},
  // optionally any extra needed header
  {'Authorization': 'Basic ' +
    new Buffer(username + ':' + passw).toString('base64')}
).then(
  console.info,
  console.error
);
```

The dance is similar to the one shown in the previous reply but it's simplified in various ways. It works well for GitHub OAuth and others services too.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `request` library whenever I need to do HTTP request in nodejs.

```
var request = require('request');
request({
     method: 'POST', 
     uri: 'http://myuri.com',
     headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 
            'AnotherHeader' : 'anotherValue' 
     }, 
     json: myjsonobj
}, (err, response, body) => {
        // handler here
})
```

there are other ways of making the request as well like `request.post()` refer [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md)